# Unity velocity acting up when rotating camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 3D platformer, and I have two movements modes: ground and air. When the player is on the ground, he moves in the direction he is facing, and in the air, is controlled by two variables called 'velX' and 'velZ'.

My problem is that when I rotate the camera in the air, and the player is going left in the air, the velocity will go left of the direction the camera is facing. I've been trying to fix it for almost a week now and I can't find any answers on how to fix my problem. I know *why* this happens, because of how this line of code works.

`moveDirection = (camera.forward * Mathf.Round(velZ)) + (camera.right * Mathf.Round(velX));`

I tried removing camera.forward/right from the moveDirection, but then the player doesn't move based on camera direction. Then, I tried added camera.forward/right where I add/subtract velX/velZ, but since camera.forward/right are floats, I am having trouble.

Here is my code:

```
velZ += acceleration * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 1.5f * Time.deltaTime;
velX += acceleration  * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 1.5f * Time.deltaTime;
if (!myCharacterController.isGrounded) {
    moveDirection = (camera.forward * Mathf.Round(velZ)) + (camera.right * Mathf.Round(velX));
}
myCharacterController.move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem very easily. I simply replaced velX and velZ(which were floats) with a Vector3 called 'airVel'.

Code:

```
airVel += acceleration * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 1.5f * Time.deltaTime;
airVel += acceleration  * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 1.5f * Time.deltaTime;
if (!myCharacterController.isGrounded) {
    moveDirection = airVel;
}
myCharacterController.move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```